# I use React hooks and React memo to prevent my functional component from re-rendering ,but not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render, react-memo

I use React.memo to control re-render, but my component still re-rendered.
my code like this:

in my Template Component:

```
const Template = (props: Props) => {
  const { propsValue, data } = props
  const [value, setValue] = useState(propsValue)

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
    props.onChange(value)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {info.type === 'input' && <Input value={value} onChange={(event, val) => handleChange(val) onBlur={(event) => handleBlur()} />
      {info.type === 'image' && <Uploader multiple value={value} uploadUrl={data.uploadUrl} onChange={(val) => handleChange(val)} />
      {info.type === 'select' && <Select onChange={(val) => handleChange(val)} />
    </div>
  )
}

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(prevProps) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps)) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}

export default React.memo(EditTemplate, areEqual)
```

in my Uploader Component:

```
const Uploader = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value)
  let { uploadUrl, multiple } = props

  const handleChange = ({ file, fileList }) => {
    if (file.status === 'done') {
      setValue(fileList)
      props.onChange(fileList)
    } else {
      setValue(fileList)
    }
  }

  return (
     <div>
       <Upload fileList={value} multiple={multiple} action={uploadUrl} onChange={handleChange} />
     </div>
  )
}

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(prevProps) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps)) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}

export default React.memo(Uploader, areEqual)
```

when I change value in Select Component, the areEqual seems like not work, the address of all images in Upload Component will reload. why...?

the performance like this:

[image]

how can I do?

Comment: React [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo): This method only exists as a **performance optimization**. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs. Straight from the docs. If `info.type` changes then `Uploader` is mounted/unmounted. Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: For those cases, you should consider using `useMemo` inside your component before re-rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `onChange` param to `Uploader` like `onChange={(val) => handleChange(val)}` so this effectively creates new function on each render and probably `React.memo` gives false positive because of this. Also in `Uploader` you have `props.onChange(fileList)` and `fileList` might also be the reason if it's a different Array instance everytime.

In addition to **@Ramesh Reddy**'s answer, you're calling `setValue` upon Select changes too, that could also be the reason, since you're using the new value as prop to `Uploader`.

If this is not the reason, you can add a codesandbox sample with reproduction of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The rerender might be because of the internal state change(`setValue(value)`). `React.memo` doesn't prevent rerender caused by a state change.

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component
> wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its
> implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: but why state change in select  lead to uploader images reload...? can't understand...

Comment: Because of the reason stated in the answer. `Uploader` is a child of the `Template` component. The function assigned to select's `onChange` is changing the state which triggers the rerender.

Comment: I try to comment out `setValue(value)` in Template Component but images still reload.

Comment: What about `props.onChange(value)`? There are a few other things that can cause a rerender. Go through the docs. Memoize things that makes sense to be memoized using `useCallback`, `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all very much~I find that the type of my value in Uploader is array, so when Select change ,`props.onChange` will be lead to change the value, so Uploader will reload.

I add useEffect in Uploader Component like this : `useEffect(() => { setValue(formatValue(props.value)) }, [JSON.stringify(props.value)])` ,and then the images will not reload...